# Swap two HTML tags which have som fix tags between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Div tag and within have 3 Elements (HTML Tags).

the first tag is : field set ,

the second tag is : div with position fix and have lot of inner tag

the third tag is : field set .

I need after checking conditions in document ready event, call function for swap only 2 field set (for example this code) and second element(div) stay fix.

please note this sample :

```
      <div id='InformationDiv'>

         <fieldset id='fieldset1'>
              ...                  
         </fieldset>

         <div id='fixDiv'>
              ...
              ...  
         </div>

         <fieldset id='fieldset2'>
              ...                  
         </fieldset>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/NnByd/

```
 var swapItems= $("#InformationDiv fieldset");
 $("#InformationDiv").prepend(swapItems.eq(1))
 $("#InformationDiv").append(swapItems.eq(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/bK7XT/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var obj1=$("#fixDiv").prev();
    var obj2=$("#fixDiv").next();
    $("#fixDiv").before(obj2);
    $("#fixDiv").after(obj1);
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
     <div id='InformationDiv'>

         <fieldset id='fieldset1'>
              fieldset1                
         </fieldset>

         <div id='fixDiv'>
              fixDiv 
         </div>

         <fieldset id='fieldset2'>
              fieldset2                 
         </fieldset>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as :

```
$("#fieldset1").detach().insertAfter("#fixDiv");
$("#fieldset2").detach().insertBefore("#fixDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
function replace() {
  var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
  var fieldset;
  var parent = fieldsets[0].parentNode;

  // Create some dummy replacement material
  var newStuff = [];
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = 'This is new';
  newStuff.push(p);
  p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = 'This is also new';
  newStuff.push(p);

  // Replace
  for (var ii=fieldsets.length;ii>0;) {
    ii--;
    fieldset = fieldsets[ii];
    parent.replaceChild(newStuff[ii], fieldset);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/Pze9s/